# kotlin extension function with livedata return null?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to write extension function which return user token from room database
but the extension function return null when  I call it

```
fun AppCompatActivity.getUserToken(): String {
   val app = AppDatabase(this)
   val userToken = app.getUserDao().getUserToken()
   var publicKey: String? = null
   userToken.observe(this, Observer { userToken ->
       publicKey = userToken.publicKey
   })
   return publicKey!!
}
```

Comment: If `getUserToken()` is returning `LiveData`, your `observe()` call will get you the value *eventually*, not immediately.

Comment: @CommonsWare he observed the liveData with `Observer`

Comment: @MJane: Yes, but then he returns `publicKey` immediately. The database I/O will not even have begun by that point.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `userToken` inside your observer? both ` val userToken = app.getUserDao().getUserToken()` and ` userToken ->` are named the same. Check if you are using the one inside observer scope

Comment: @CommonsWare the block inside the observer is called whenever the response is received. written in a document of liveData.java ` The events are dispatched on the main thread. If LiveData already has data
     * set, it will be delivered to the observer.`

Comment: "the block inside the observer is called whenever the response is received" -- correct. It then updates a local variable. By the time the `Observer` is called, this extension function will have long since returned its original (`null`) value of `publicKey`. "If LiveData already has data * set, it will be delivered to the observer" -- and if this is a Room DAO, as I suspect, then it will be a brand-new `LiveData` and it will not have any data yet.

Answer (score 2):

As CommonsWare explained, you are return the newly created LiveData with `null` value. What you can do is instead of returning value from the function use Callback

```
fun AppCompatActivity.getUserToken(callBack:((String)->Unit)) {
    val app = AppDatabase(this)
    val userToken = app.getUserDao().getUserToken()
    
    userToken.observe(this, Observer { userToken ->
        callback(userToken.publicKey)
    })
    
}
```

In your Activity you need to call like this

```
getUserToken() { userToken ->
   //Use your Token and do work related to UserToken from here
   
}
```